# Regular expression for function call containing two arguments

Tags: regex

In many languages, a function call consists of a slug followed by any number of arguments surrounded by parentheses, like so:

```
my_function(); // no arguments
my_function(one_argument);
my_function(first_argument,second_argument);
my_function(first_argument,second_argument,third_argument);
```

What regular expression will match exactly the case with two arguments (the *third* case in the pseudocode above)?

The "obvious answer" would be something like `\w+\([^)]+,[^)]+\)`. However, the special meaning of the parentheses breaks this expression.

Comment: In general, you cannot do this with regex. You need at least a context-free parser for programming languages which is more than regex can do. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#The_hierarchy) Best you can do with regex in an expression that can handle simple cases. For example, consider the situation when someone passes `(a+foo(b, "(\"text\")"))*c` as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might write the pattern like this using a negated character class and also omit matching the comma:

```
\w+\([^,)]+,[^,)]+\);
```

**Explanation**

- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `\(` Match `(1
- `[^,)]+` Match 1+ chars other than `,` and `)`
- `,` Match the single comma
- `[^,)]+` Match 1+ chars other than `,` and `)`
- `\);` Match `);`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eoyIfg/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
/\w+\([a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*, ?[a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*\);/g
```

[RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/CS0C8k/1)

| Segment | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ``` \w+\([a-zA-Z_$] ``` | Any letter, number, or underscore one or more times, then a literal `(`, then any letter, underscore, or dollar sign |
| ``` [\w$]*, ? ``` | Any letter, number, underscore, or dollar sign zero or more times, then a literal `,`, then a single space or nothing |
| ``` [a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*\); ``` | Any letter, underscore, or dollar sign, then any letter, number, underscore, or dollar sign zero or more times, then a literal `);` |

Note that each parameter is `[a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*` which follows the rules for naming a JavaScript variable:

- May consist of any letter, number, underscore, or dollar sign.
- Must start with a letter, underscore, or dollar sign.

For a PHP variable: `$[a-zA-Z_]\w*`

For a Python variable: `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_]*`